# ImportError: No module named torch

Tags: python

I'm trying to install this framework from Github called torch2trt (found here:https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt).

I ran the following code in a Python terminal to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt
cd torch2trt
python setup.py install
```

but ended up with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

I have already installed pytorch using `pip install torch torchvision`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3 install torch torchvision` instead? I think you could be running the setup script in Python 3 but install the pip packages for Python 2

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you install `torch` in one Python but you run code in other Python. Check `python -V` and `pip -V` or use `python -m pip install ... `

Comment: I am also having the same problem, I can see it is installed with `pip list` and `pip3 list`

Answer (score 3):

Try running everything in `python3`:

```
python3 -m pip install torch torchvision
```

followed by :

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux,

```
which python
which pip
```

In Windows power shell

```
where python
where pip
```

Check if both pip and python are from same parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

`python` defaults to `python2`

So you should change `python setup.py install` to `python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can check the PyTorch page and try another version. https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

I would try this one first.

pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 torchvision==0.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html